# Restore RDS DB instance from snapshot with multi-AZ deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I need to create snapshots of my RDS Aurora DB instances for backup purposes. The source DB Instance is a multi-AZ deployment instance.

I want to be able to restore an instance from a snapshot with multi-AZ deployment enabled, but it won't let me select that option (disabled).

Is there a reason why?

How can I restore the exact same instance (with multi-AZ deployment)?

Comment: You can not restore snapshot to an existing instance. Restoring will create a new instance. Does this clarify?

Comment: Yes I'm aware, new instance is fine but I want to be able to make it multi-AZ deployment. But that option is disabled/ greyed out.

Comment: That is strange. Did you select all other fields? DB instance type etc.

Comment: Yep, filled in.

Comment: This is answered in this post.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928534/cant-create-multi-az-aurora-rds-instance